# Internal 500 Error for controller service : HDF Nifi with 3 Node cluster

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-dataflow

I have installed HDF 2.1.2 with 3 node Nifi 1.1 cluster and I am trying to configure controller service in it. I created a simple ExecuteHQL processor which depends on ThriftConnectionPool controller service.

I dragged ExecuteProcessor on canvas and as soon as I clicked on gear icon for configuring controller service , it throws runtime exception in log.

```
Attempting request for (anonymous) GET http://<hostname>:9090/nifi-api/flow/process-groups/83490f62-015c-1000-0000-00004da8f033/controller-

HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Please look in nifi-user.log or nifi-app.log and provide the error and stacktrace that correspond with 500 error.

Comment: @BryanBende I have logs on secure Nifi cluster.It bit time consuming collect logs from there. At this moment I can see in log there is an exception around org.apache.nifi.cluster.manager.AllowableValueEntityMerger class which is returning NullPointerException.

Comment: It is going to be hard to say without seeing the stacktrace and/or the code for your custom components, but double-check all the PropertyDescriptors that use AllowableValues in your processor and controller service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had duplicate controller service jar - one actual and another symlink which was causing issue.